# Input from PHP generated form is not being recorded

Tags: php, html, post, isset

The issue I have been experiencing deals with input from HTML which was generated using PHP echo statements. Here is the function I have that outputs the form:

```
function confirm_recipients()
    {

        echo "<form action = ' ' name ='email_options' method='post'>";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='sendRecipients' value='Yes, I want to send the emails' >";
        echo "</form>";
    }
```

Later on in the same PHP page, I call the function and then check to see if the submit button was set.

`confirm_recipients();`

```
if (isset($_POST['sendRecipients'])) 
    {
    //perform actions
    }
```

However, this code is not functional seeing as even when the submit button is set (clicked by the user), the if statement block is never executed. Perhaps there is an issue with posting from the same file I want to "read in" from? Thanks for any advice.

Updates

Thank you for such immediate response. Sadly none of the suggestions have worked (removing the space in the action value or the suggestion made by user623952). No errors have been reported, the button is just failing to be set. I am looking for other places in the file that might have errors, perhaps in the order I call the function.

Comment: Delete the space in `action = ' '` - just make it `action=''`.  See if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Yes. Agreed Ed. Also, you should set the display_errors on to see what is going on.

Comment: @user2981403 - can you update your post to clarify the issue you are having, please?  Are you getting any errors?  Have any of the suggestions helped?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works fine for me:

```
<?php

print "<pre>".print_r($_POST,true)."</pre>"; 

confirm_recipients();

function confirm_recipients() { 
    echo "<form action = ' ' name ='email_options' method='post'>";
    echo "<input type='submit' name='sendRecipients' value='Yes, I want to send the emails' >";
    echo "</form>";
}


if (isset($_POST['sendRecipients']))
{
    print "<br/>sendRecipients is set!<br/>"; 
}

?>
```

I think your problem might be somewhere else in the code.

Answer (score -1):

1. It's okay to POST the form data to the same script that contains the form. Change the action attribute to the URL of the script, do not set it to whitespace, which is what you did.
2. I don't think the value of a submit input is sent as part of the POST. Try  using an input type="hidden" with the name 'sendRecipients'.